# iOS chart framework: TapkuLibrary, Core-Plot or any. Tap of point calls method?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I'm working on an iOS project where tapping on a particular point in a graph should take the user to another scene. Basically, to be able to trigger a method from the user tapping on a point if this makes more sense. Is there any of these frameworks which would make this easy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Plot can certainly do this. It includes several example programs that demonstrate how to set up a delegate to be notified when a point is touched on the plot. How you respond to that notification is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend giving [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com) a try, they have [many built-in interactive features](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobicharts/product-tour/#tabs-4).

*As a full disclosure, I work for the parent company that owns shinobi controls*

Comment: I use ShinobiControls and I am very satisfied with, and I am not affiliated with ShinobiControls in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  TapKu and Core-Plot both have user interaction, if I recall.  Core-Plot is definitely powerful, but I'll be damned if it's lightweight or easy to use. TapKu is definitely lightweight and easy to use, but I needed a little more juice for my charts ... like multiple lines, negative numbers, missing data points, not just the single line (with a "goal").

Right now I've got a bit of a hybrid between [Josh Buhler's GRChart](https://github.com/joshbuhler/GRChart), [Kryali's MultiTouchS7GraphView](https://github.com/kryali/MultiTouchS7GraphView), [BugCloud's Customed-s7graphview](https://github.com/bugcloud/Customed-s7graphview) and some Frankensteinian menagerie of my own junk to power my chart.

I'm personally pretty fond of Josh's GRChart and recenty [Honcheng's iOSPlot](https://github.com/honcheng/iOSPlot) for their sheer simplicity (lending well to customization) and frankly, their underdogishness.  Neither of those have touch gestures, but it wouldn't take much work at all to reuse the code from BugCloud's *xAxisWasTapped*: method, or other methods from any of the other touch-enabled charts.

Comment: We'll see. As far as I can tell, TapKu only offers values when tapped over a point. I didn't see any methods to call when someone tapped. I think I'll have to figure out Core-Plot. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this?  "TapKu only offers values when tapped over a point". More to the point, though ... Did you happen to check out any of the other four libraries I suggested?  Kryali's and BugCloud's might be less of a mental nightmare since they do touches too.